# What is the exact reason behind the usage of がin the following phrase?

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

Hopefully, just another quick one here.

In the phrase

> 日本で東京スカイツリーが一番高い建物です。

what is the reason behind using が as opposed to は in the phrase

> 東京スカイツリーは日本で一番高い建物です。

Sorry if this is a silly question... But thank you nonetheless!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 日本で東京スカイツリーが一番高い建物です。

It is Tokyo Skytree that is the tallest building in Japan.

This describes which one is the tallest. が is used to feature something particular rather than the others.

> 東京スカイツリーは日本で一番高い建物です。

Tokyo Skytree is the tallest building in Japan.

This just describes Tokyo Skytree.

Comment: Spot on. Just to add to your answer, although there are several differences between が and は, one difference is that if が can be used to put emphasis on what precedes it, whereas は can be used to emphasise what comes after it. Therefore the second sentence reads more as a simple description of tokyo skytree, but the first is an explanation of which building is the tallest.

Comment: The first sentence could be rewritten using は: 日本の一番高い建物は東京スカイツリーです。Here the emphasis is on what comes after は as being the important information.